# Parsing file with bash and append prefix to each line if it doesn't match pattern

Tags: bash

I would like to parse each line of my file that looks like this:

```
www.hello.by
https://www.google.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
www.fedia.com
```

I want my script append `http://` to each line if it doesn't start with `http://` or `https://`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you even try to implement that? It's super simple..

You just need to read the file line by line. You can do this like that:

```
while read line ; do
    echo $line
done < your_file
```

Then you have to check if your line starts with http:// or https://:

```
if [[ $line =~ ^https?:// ]] ; then
    echo $line
fi
```

..and add http if it does not:

```
if [[ $line =~ ^https?:// ]] ; then
    echo $line
else
    echo http://$line
fi
```

Putting it all together you get:

```
while read line ; do                                                                                                                                                                                        
    if [[ $line =~ ^https?:// ]] ; then                                                                                                                                                                     
        echo $line                                                                                                                                                                                          
    else                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        echo http://$line                                                                                                                                                                                   
    fi                                                                                                                                                                                                      
done < your_file
```

You may want to save changes to a file, then redirect the output to a temporary file first and replace existing file with it at the end:

```
while read line ; do                                                                                                                                                                                        
    if [[ $line =~ ^https?:// ]] ; then                                                                                                                                                                     
        echo $line                                                                                                                                                                                          
    else                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        echo http://$line                                                                                                                                                                                   
    fi                                                                                                                                                                                                      
done < data > data.tmp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
mv data{.tmp,}
```

Alternative awk version:

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /^https?/) print; else print "http://"$0}' data
```

Modify the file:

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /^https?/) print; else print "http://"$0}' your_file  > your_file.tmp ; mv your_file{.tmp,}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed '\|^https\{0,1\}://|!s,^,http://,' file

http://www.hello.by
https://www.google.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.fedia.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following sed command

```
sed -i '/https\?:\/\//{t;}
s/^/http:\/\//
' YOUR_FILE
```